# How to solve error "o rule to make target"?

Tags: c++, qt

This Error pops up while I try to Compile the Project Map of Cartotype, I followed The Instruction on The Cartotype Documentation, but at this point I couldn't do any progress, help please !

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target 'G:/QT/Projects/cartotype-eval/CartoType-Public/src/apps/Maps/../../../../cartotype_windows_sdk_evaluation_5.10.7/CartoType/bin/15.0/x64/DebugDLL/libcartotyped.a', needed by 'debug/CartoTypeMaps.exe'.  Stop.
```

My colleage tested same project on QT Linux - Ubuntu, and it worked smoothly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you're using MinGW since the buildtool is looking for `foo.a`. You need to simply look at that error and understand what it means: a library it needs is missing. Until you provide that library, it won't build. That's the simple part. The hard part is that [according to the SDK overview](http://www.cartotype.com/developers/evaluation-sdks), `CartoType` comes with `.lib` libraries only, not `.a` libraries. But modern MinGW supports `.lib` files, so you only need to convince it to look for the `.lib` file, not `.a` file. Most likely, your build scripts have the reference to `.a`, or no full filename whatsoever.

If you're using QMAKE, you likely have something like:

```
LIBS += -LX:/cartotype_windows_sdk_evaluation_5.10.7/CartoType/bin/15.0/x64/DebugDLL cartotyped
```

Instead, you'd want:

```
LIBS += X:/cartotype_windows_sdk_evaluation_5.10.7/CartoType/bin/15.0/x64/DebugDLL/cartotyped.lib
```